# conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int error in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to run a query, but after a while it gave me the Conversion failed error. Here's the query I am trying to run:

> 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ...... to int'

```
Declare @ID varchar(max)
set @ID = '33,  691, 688, 58,  42, 3'


select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 
where rpt_id in (@ID )
```

I'm passing rpt_id  to the query as a varchar variable.Any idea please?

Comment: There must be a value in `rpt_id` that cannot be converted to `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Column rpt_id has type INT.

Comment: Okay. So you mean to say you're passing `rpt_cat_id` like this: `'3300718,3305691,3234688,3358162,3423680,3406570,3368217,3363510'`?

Answer (score 0):

Compare varchar with varchar can fix your problem, assuming tsgb_extract_110107 is a table

```
select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 
where rpt_id in ('3300718',
'3305691',
'3234688',
'3358162',
'3423680',
'3406570',
'3368217',
'3363510',
)
```

**EDIT**

You can split the `@ID` into a table then using join

```
Declare @ID varchar(max)
set @ID = '33,  691, 688, 58,  42, 3'


DECLARE @xml as xml
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@ID, ',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

;WITH criteria AS
(
    SELECT LTRIM(N.value('.', 'varchar(10)')) as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
)
select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 INNER JOIN criteria ON rpt_id = criteria.value
```

Comment: I'm passing rpt_id as a parameter to Query.

Comment: @Tom You cannot use `in` in that way

Comment: Then how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 
where ISNUMERIC(rpt_id) And Convert(numeric(18,0),rpt_id) in (3300718,
3305691,
3234688,
3358162,
3423680,
3406570,
3368217,
3363510,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have a string splitter. Here is one taken from Aaron Bertrand's [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_XML]
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

Then, use that function in your `WHERE` clause:

```
select
    listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 
where
    rpt_id in (
        select cast(rtrim(ltrim(value)) as int) from dbo.SplitStrings_XML(@ID)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
Declare @ID varchar(max)
set @ID = '33,  691, 688, 58,  42, 3'
declare @str nvarchar(max)

set @str = 'select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
from tsgb_extract_110107 
where rpt_id in ('+@ID+' )' 
exec sp_executesql @str
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
--create table tsgb_extract_110107 (rpt_id int , listing_id int, name_en varchar(50) , phone varchar(10))           

   --insert into tsgb_extract_110107 values (1,1,'abc','123'),(33,33,'abc','33'),(691,691,'abc','691'),(58,58,'abc','58'),(3,3,'abc','3')

   Declare @ID nvarchar(max)
   set @ID = '33,  691, 688, 58,  42, 3'

   Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
   set @sql = 'select listing_id, rpt_id, name_en, phone
   from tsgb_extract_110107 
   where rpt_id in ( '+ @ID + ' ) '
   select @sql
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

**What helped me was this function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[f_SplitString] (@sep char(1), @s varchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN (
        WITH Pieces(pn, start, stop) AS (
          SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
          FROM Pieces
          WHERE stop > 0
       )
       SELECT pn,
       SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
       FROM Pieces
    )
```

**Put in where clause like this:**

```
where Ids in (SELECT s FROM [dbo].[f_SplitString](',', @Ids))
```